# can I make firefox remember what spellcheck dictionary to use for particular web sites?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

I read and write on the web in two different languages and it would be really handy to `teach` firefox to use this spellcheck dictionary for that and that website while the default one would be english.

Is anything like that possible?

( win XP + ff 3.6 )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with the add-on [**Dictionary Switcher**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dictionary-switcher/):

> Toggles between the installed
>   dictionaries automatically or manually
>   and displays the currently selected
>   dictionary in the status bar.

[image]

Comment: it works really nicely. Automatic detection doesn't work for me but I can switch to the right dict with two clicks ...